# (direct) sum vs span of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a difference between the span of subspaces and the sum of them in linear algebra?  They both seem to just be the set of all linear combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of linear subspaces is again a subspace (state the proof!). As you pointed out, this resulting subspace is precisely their span, i.e. for a vector space $V$ and subspaces $U_1,\dots,U_r \subset V$ with $r \in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds:

$$ 
\operatorname{span}(U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_r) 
= \sum_{i = 1}^r U_i 
= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^r b_i : b_i \in U_i\right\}.
$$

As a matter of fact, every subspace $U \subset V$ generates itself, i.e.

$$ \operatorname{span}(U) = U. $$

**EDIT:** As @ErikWong pointed out, the above equality may lead to conflicts with the definition of **direct** sums if you consider the **direct** sum of an **arbitrary** family of subspaces $(U_i)_{i \in I}$. On the one side the span of the elements of this family, $\operatorname{span}_{i \in I}(U_i)$, will always be well defined, whereas on the other side, in order to be allowed to construct the direct sum, you additionally have to assure the linear independence of all involved subspaces.

Comment: Would be nice to also address the case of $\{U_i : i \in I\}$ where $I$ is an infinite index set.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I think the statement about the union of subspaces will continue to hold for arbitrary unions. However, I'm not sure about how the sum of a family of subspaces $\left(U_i\right)_{i \in I}$ would be defined, as the span of a subspace is defined as a finite linear combination. Maybe something like this: $\sum_{i \in I} U_i := \left\{ \sum_{j = 1}^r b_j : b_j \in U_{i_j} \text{ for } i_j  \in I \right\}$?

Comment: Yeah, the [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) is also defined in terms of sums of _finite_ subsets, so the two definitions are compatible.  It depends a little on whether the OP really means direct sum.  If the $U_i$ contain linear dependencies, I'd avoid calling it the direct sum of subspaces because it conflicts with the notion of direct sum of vector spaces.  But it would still make sense to talk about their span.

Comment: @ErickWong: I edited the post trying to reflect the point you made.

Comment: do you happen to have a link to proving the above statement? thanks

Comment: @jamesblack No. It just made (and still makes) sense, therefore I did not spend time researching it. Is there anything unclear from the post?